# Rubberduck VBA: What can cause a Resolver Error?

Tags: vba, rubberduck

Thank to this question : [Rubberduck UI submenus are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601588/rubberduck-ui-submenus-are-disabled/41601886#41601886), I know that I may have to hit the "Refresh button" to use [RubberduckVBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/).

One of the error that can follow is apparently the "Resolver Error".

[image]

**What are the different cases in which such a Resolver Error may occur?**

Comment: [This](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/02/06/what-do-parsing-and-resolving-mean-anyway/) might help.

Comment: @JohnColeman the documentation is rather thin on this subject. OP: what version are you using? The parser/resolver has seen very significant changes lately. You can copy version information to the clipboard by clicking the "version" box in the "about" dialog.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I noticed that hence changed my comment.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon My version was 2.2.0.3439-pre. I have now installed the 2.2.0.3723-pre, but I still got the same error. Version 2.2.0.3723
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.16299.0, x64
Host Product: Microsoft Office 2016 x64
Host Version: 16.0.8730.2175
Host Executable: EXCEL.EXE

Comment: Thanks for reporting it! We have hundreds of passing automated tests for the parser & resolver, but it's hard to cover *everything* =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At least one of the case is the following:**

**A Function or Sub doesn't compile and the developer is not aware of that when running the VBA project because the Sub is never called.**

***Solution:***

**This "junk" code can be spotted in [Trace-level logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52081939/9956726) of Rubberduck.**

For exemple in my case:

```
Sub CleanSheetOut()
Worksheets(sheetOut).Range("A1:XFD10485576").Clear
Worksheets(sheetOut).Range("A1:XFD10485576").Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
       .TintAndShade = 0
     .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End Sub
```

...was incorrect (didn't compile) but was never called, so the project was running fine but Rubberduck couldn't resolve.

The correct code :

```
Sub CleanSheetOut()
   Worksheets(sheetOut).Range("A1:XFD10485576").Clear
   With Worksheets(sheetOut).Range("A1:XFD10485576").Interior
      .Pattern = xlNone
      .TintAndShade = 0
      .PatternTintAndShade = 0
   End With
End Sub
```

...compiles and lets Rubberduck parse and resolve normally.

The logs: 
[image]
... showed the faulty Sub and in which module I could find it.

Insight from the Rubberduck development team:

> Whether the VBE compiles on the fly depends on the compile settings in
>   the bottom right of the Editor tab of the Tools->Options menu.
>
> We actually try to compile the project and warn the user that the
>   project does not compile. However, the forementioned VBE settings can
>   interfere with that. Moreover, compilation before refresh might be
>   deactivated in Rubberduck's own settings.

See this [Github thread](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/4323) for more details.

Comment: You sure this wasn’t spotted? When you clicked on the x indicating a compile error where did it take you?

Comment: When I say "not spotted", I mean "not spotted by me, when running the main sub of the project". I don't mean "not spotted by Rubberduck".

Comment: Lol. Sorry! My bad.

Comment: I wasn't super explicit. I updated my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 6):

#### TL;DR: Rubberduck is past due for a new "official" release!

> Disclaimer: I manage & contribute to the Rubberduck OSS project.

An exception was thrown while traversing the parse trees. It's hard to tell exactly what happened, because parsing+resolving VBA code is a [very complex, multiple-steps process](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/inside-rubberduck-pt-2/).

To find out specifically what went wrong, you need to look at the logs - logging being disabled by default (it's rather verbose), you need to enable it through the *settings* dialog:

[image: Rubberduck settings dialog]

Set the *minimum log level* to **Trace** for the full gory details of everything the parser/resolver is doing, or **Error** for a less verbose log that only includes the exception information; you can then post this log (or parts of it) into a [new issue](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/new), and the project devs will promptly tag/label it accordingly, inspect the log/exception details, and determine whether the problem was fixed in a later pre-release build, or if it's a new bug that needs to be fixed.

Since pretty much every single feature needs an accurate understanding of the code in the VBE, Rubberduck devs take parser/resolver issues extremely seriously.

If you're using the latest "green" release (v2.2.0), I'm pretty sure the problem was fixed since then. Latest "pre-release" build has annoying problems with the *autocompletion* feature (will definitely be fixed by v2.3.0), but the resolver works very well now :)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to open an issue.